# Convert IPv4 into Hexadecimal in postgresql using Function/Procedure

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, hex, ipv4

I am writing a postgresql function/procedure to convert IPv4 column from a table into Hexadecimal for another table.

Function to convert IPv4 to Hex :-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IPTOHEX(ip in varchar) returns varchar as $iptohex$
DECLARE
period1st NUMERIC(3);
period2nd NUMERIC(3);
period3rd NUMERIC(3);
period4th NUMERIC(3);
octet1st varchar(3);
octet2nd varchar(3);
octet3rd varchar(3);
octet4th varchar(3);
hex1st NUMERIC(3);
hex2nd NUMERIC(3);
hex3rd NUMERIC(3);
hex4th NUMERIC(3);
hex varchar(8);
begin
         period1st := split_part(ip,'.',1);
         period2nd := split_part(ip,'.',2);
         period3rd := split_part(ip,'.',3);
     period4th := split_part(ip,'.',4);
     hex1st := to_hex(period1st);
     hex2nd := to_hex(period2nd);
     hex3rd := to_hex(period3rd);
     hex4th := to_hex(period4th);
         octet1st := lpad(hex1st,2,'0');
         octet2nd := lpad(hex2nd,2,'0');
         octet3rd := lpad(hex3rd,2,'0');
         octet4th := lpad(hex4th,2,'0');
         hex := upper(octet1st || octet2nd || octet3rd || octet4th);
         return(hex);
end;
$iptohex$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The table - sample1 which consists of IPv4 address consists of 5 columns in which 3 columns are IPv4 address.So whenever I add. delete or update row in sample1 then same should be done in sample2 table but as hexadecimal. So I wrote below procedure to convert the column values from sample1 table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IPTOHEXA() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $iptohexa$
   BEGIN
                DELETE FROM sample2;
            DECLARE
              range_cur CURSOR  IS
               SELECT subnet_address_range, subnet_address_start, subnet_address_end, subnet_mask_length, fno_tadig_code FROM sample1;
            BEGIN
               FOR range_rec IN range_cur LOOP
                INSERT INTO sample2 VALUES(iptohex(range_rec.subnet_address_range), range_rec.subnet_mask_length, iptohex(range_rec.subnet_address_start), iptohex(range_rec.subnet_address_end), range_rec.fno_tadig_code);
              END LOOP;
            END;
            END;
   $iptohexa$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I use below trigger on sample1 table

```
CREATE TRIGGER EL_SOURCE_FNO_IP_ADDRESS_TRIG1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON SOURCE_FNO_IP_ADDRESS FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE IPTOHEXA();
```

But I get error like while trying to insert rows in sample1 table

```
eventlink=>  INSERT INTO sample1 values('1.66.0.0','22','1.66.0.0','1.66.3.255','JPNDO');
ERROR:  function to_hex(numeric) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT to_hex(period1st)
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:  SELECT to_hex(period1st)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function iptohex(character varying) line 21 at assignment
SQL statement "INSERT INTO sample2 VALUES(iptohex(range_rec.subnet_address_range), range_rec.subnet_mask_length, iptohex(range_rec.subnet_address_start), iptohex(range_rec.subnet_address_end), range_rec.fno_tadig_code)"
PL/pgSQL function iptohexa() line 9 at SQL statement
```

Can someone help me in sorting this error?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `to_hex()` takes an integer not numeric value. See here [String functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-string.html). Either change the  DECLAREs to integer or cast the values to integer per the HINT.

Comment: Thank you, I tried with integer and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Nice function, but by cascading the functions calls it can be redused to a single statement. Then the function itself can be converted to a SQL function.

```
create or replace 
function ip4_to_hex(ip4_in text)
  returns text
 language sql
 immutable strict
as $$  
select lpad(to_hex(split_part(ip4_in,'.',1)::int),2,'0') || 
       lpad(to_hex(split_part(ip4_in,'.',2)::int),2,'0') ||
       lpad(to_hex(split_part(ip4_in,'.',3)::int),2,'0') ||
       lpad(to_hex(split_part(ip4_in,'.',4)::int),2,'0') ;
$$;
```

See [example here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3e2c7014ab42ac62832608a665feac7e).